# Adding two characters and assigning the result to an int in C

Tags: c

```
int main(){

 char a = -5;
 char b = -6;
 int c = a+b;
 return 0;
}
```

I'm getting different results for the above code in different architectures, using `gcc`.

on `x86` the variable `c` is properly sign extended and I get `-11`.

On some other architectures `c` is not sign extended, you get the result of `a+b` bit-casted to an `int` and I get `501`.

Is this undefined behaviour?

Comment: YES. marking it as `signed char` did the trick. I didn't know that, thank you.

Comment: How can you know what result you got? There is no output from this program. With optimization on, a compiler will eliminate everything other than returning zero from `main`.

Comment: I agree with @EricPostpischil that the behavior is not undefined when converting the negative number to an (unsigned) `char`. This situation is addressed in [§6.3.1.3 ¶2 of the ISO C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char` is sometimes an unsigned type. Use `signed char` or `unsigned char` if you need to be explicit about it. Adding a print to your program and compiling under both circumstances shows your behaviour:

```
$ make example && ./example
cc     example.c   -o example
-11
```

You can force GCC to use the unsigned char by default:

```
$ CFLAGS=-funsigned-char make example && ./example
cc -funsigned-char    example.c   -o example
501
```

I would recommend to always use `unsigned char` and `signed char` in code, unless you use it only for ASCII character storage.